# eglinfo ACCEL_WORKING query results in permission denied

Tags: amdgpu, mesa, drm

When I execute eglinfo from the mesa-utils package, I get failures:

```
$ eglinfo
...
GBM platform:
amdgpu_device_initialize: amdgpu_query_info(ACCEL_WORKING) failed (-13)
amdgpu: amdgpu_device_initialize failed.
amdgpu_device_initialize: amdgpu_query_info(ACCEL_WORKING) failed (-13)
amdgpu: amdgpu_device_initialize failed.
...
```

I have traced the `amdgpu_query_info()` to libdrm in the file `amdgpu/amdgpu_gpu_info.c`

The `drmCommandWrite()` fails with errno 13: **Permission Denied**.

Initially I thought this was trivial to fix, as I noticed that the devices in `/dev/dri/*` had group ownership `video` and `render`.
But after making the user part of these groups, and rebooting, the error is still present.

Why does `drmCommandWrite()` fail with denied permissions? I have no such issue when running the integrated graphics and the iris driver.

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
    driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Display: wayland server: X.org v: 1.21.1.4 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.3
    compositor: gnome-shell v: 43.1 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: amdgpu resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD Radeon RX 580 Series (polaris10 LLVM 15.0.2 DRM
    3.49 6.1.6-060106-generic) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.2.1
```

OS: Ubuntu 22.10

### update

The permission denied error goes away when running as root.

A [relevant comment](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/drm/-/issues/52#note_619180) on a gitlab issue explains that the display server should have authenticated access to `/dev/dri/card0` first.